# How to mock a ConnectionError for an integration test in GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, integration-testing

Building API functions/handlers that use a transactional state so if one process fails, the entire transaction rollsback.

The process is storing a file in a cloud storage bucket first and then some metadata into firestore.

Currently stuck on how to mock out a connectionerror, timeouterror (or any general error to the cloud function) and how to replicate this in a live integration test.

any advice would be much appreciated.